# Magento 1.7.0.2 Pagination at the bottom not working

Tags: magento, pagination

Assistance please, I am very new to Magento and have set up a store with many categories and over 400 products .

Pagination works fine at the top of all category listings however is not at the bottom.

Would someone please help me to allow pagination at the bottom of product listings.

I am using Magento 1.7.0.2.

I have searched around for solutions, spent days at it and can not find anything that will fix this.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Remove from bottom of 
>   app/design/frontend/default/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml
> ```
>
> fallowing line:

```
echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?>

then replace by
echo $this->getToolbarBlock()->
setTemplate('catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>

echo $this->getToolbarBlock()->
setTemplate('catalog/product/list/toolbar_bottom.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```